# How to merge two codes?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new at programming  and was working on this project where I had written a code that reads an integer and displays, using asterisks, a filled and hollow square, placed next to each other but I am facing a but of an issue.

These are my codes and I know they are separate but I want to merge them to print the patterns side by side.

```
integer=int(input("Enter an integer:"))

for i in range(integer):

    for j in range(integer+integer):

        print("*",end="")

    print()


print("*"*integer)

for i in range(integer-2):

    print("*"+" "*(integer-2)+"*")

print("*"*integer)
```

expected output:

```
*****   *****

*****   *   *

*****   *   *        

*****   *   *

*****   *****
```

Actual output:

```
*****   

*****   

*****          

*****   

*****   

*****

*   *

*   *        

*   *

*****
```

Comment: Instead of using `print`, save the strings in a list, combine, and only then `print` them out. Think of a `print` statement as the final output on screen, and once you print something, it should already be in the form you need it to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go.

```
integer=int(input("Enter an integer:"))


print("*"*integer + "  " + "*"*integer)

for i in range(integer-2):
    print("*"*integer + "  " + "*" + " "*(integer-2) + "*")

print("*"*integer + "  " + "*"*integer)
```

Output:

```
Enter an integer: 5

*****  *****
*****  *   *
*****  *   *
*****  *   *
*****  *****
```

Alternatively, here is one much easier to understand:

```
integer=int(input("Enter an integer:"))



full = "*"*integer
cap = full + "  " + full
hollow = "*" + " "*(integer-2) + "*"

print(cap)
for i in range(integer-2):
    print(full + "  " + hollow)
print(cap)
```

Produces identical output

Answer (score 0):

This code works by separating the two unique lines:

```
integer=int(input("Enter an integer:"))


print("*"*integer + "  " + "*"*integer)

for i in range(integer-2):
    print("*"*integer + "  " + "*" + " "*(integer-2) + "*")

print("*"*integer + "  " + "*"*integer)
```